# Wildfly Management API : What is URL for list Servergroups?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-16, wildfly-26

How to fetch server group details using Wildfly Management API

```
https://wildfly.prod.idntegrator.cosng.net/management?operation=attribute&name=server-group

{
    "outcome" : "failed",
    "failure-description" : "WFLYCTL0201: Unknown attribute 'servergroup'",
    "rolled-back" : true
}
```

I am not able to find much information here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The%20HTTP%20management%20API.html

I tried from Jboss CLI but it has no attribute like servergroup but has /server-group=generic type notation not sure how to put in rest call

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: What are you attempting to get? There is no `server-group` attribute as you state so it can't read it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: I want to check each servergroup state on each nodes. I want to check details of datasource within servergroup's subsystem etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to read just the server groups from the [HTTP Management API](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#The_HTTP_management_API). The best you could do is something like:

http://localhost:9990/management/?operation=resource

This would include an array of the server groups.

```
"server-group": {
    "main-server-group": null,
    "other-server-group": null
}
```

From CLI however you can use the `read-children-names` operation.

```
/:read-children-names(child-type=server-group)
```

Example output:

```
[domain@localhost:9990 /] /:read-children-names(child-type=server-group)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [
        "main-server-group",
        "other-server-group"
    ]
}
```

Comment: How can i get health of servergroup if it is up and running or is it down? Is it way to deep dive in servergroup using Management API (like subsystems; listing queues; Datasources etc.)? Lot's of search i did but not getting any point.

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using? With CLI it would be easier or if you use the Java Management API. I'm pretty sure the web console has some things too.

Comment: Using Wildfly 16 as of now. (I can see some example somewhere like we can fetch statistics like this -> "http://localhost:9990/management/subsystem/datasources/data-source/ExampleDS/statistics/jdbc?include-runtime=true&recursive=true").

But how to do it with servergroup? I need to expose this api to external party as they consume API only.

Comment: Also i think the examples mostly applicable to standalone. I am not even able to load server-state "WFLYCTL0201: Unknown attribute 'server-state'",

Comment: Yes the examples are for standalone. You can use wildcards, `*`, in the path. However, you can't see statistics about a data-source from a `server-group`. Something like `http://localhost:9990/management/host/master/server/%2a/subsystem/datasources/data-source/ExampleDS/statistics/%2a/?operation=resource&include-runtime=true&json.pretty=1` may work.